# startActivityForResult and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity A which starts a new activity B with startActivityForResult. 
Activity B is restarted several times with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, so when the user clicks on back, B puts on data with `setResult()` and comes back to Activity A.
 However, the data is missing. `onActivityResult` in A is invoked with intent to null and resultCode by default.

I know that, in fact, is the right behaviour since `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` discards previous activities, but I wonder if there is some workaround to achieve this (apart from obvious options like avoiding restarting B)

Comment: maybe using global (static) variables. Not really elegant but should work.

Comment: I agree, it would be a feasible solution, although not elegant

Answer (score 3):

Add both `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to your launch intents when you restart Activity B.

```
activityBIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Also relaunching Activity B will call `onNewIntent(Intent)`, however `getIntent()` will still deliver the older (original) intent.

> Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can
>   use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.